# What do the three dots on the network icon mean?

Tags: wingpanel, wifi, networking, icons

Trying to diagnose my sudden lack of wifi, but I have no idea what this icon means.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot, please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't recreate the problem as it seems to be resolved. FWIW, though, it was basically the same icon that appears with airplane mode enabled (three terminals grayed out), except it's three white dots like an ellipsis in the middle instead of a white X in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi problems after restart or suspend](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/wifi-problems-after-restart-or-suspend)

Answer (score 1):

If you had wifi and then suddenly it disappeared then you should first try switching off and on wifi and if doesn't work then just restart network manager with `sudo service network-manager restart`.

If you still have no internet then just restart your computer.

I have the same problem sometimes. I couldn't find out better solution.

:)

Comment: If it happens again I'll give it a go, but it only happened while I was trying to get [this fix](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/9806/7863) working and messed up at some point along the way. And I'm not TOO interested in trying to recreate it ;P

Comment: Well, It is jest restart Of your wifi, so you can use it whenever you have problem with internet. From my experience it happens sometimes even when you don't play with wifi. So if something's is wrong, now you know how to restart it without rebooting computer . :)

Answer (score 0):

There are various forms of this:

[Wifi problems after restart or suspend](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1382/170)

[Wifi down after waking up from a long suspend](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10856/170)

[WIFI sometimes not working](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10289/170)

Losing wifi connection is a Ubuntu 16.04 wifi issue: [16.04 LTS wifi connection issues](https://askubuntu.com/q/762198/47206).

The change of icon is related to that too - but the form of the icon may vary depending on the icon-set.

It became a rare occurrence for me after I did this: https://askubuntu.com/a/768268/47206

When it still happens I do  `service network-manager restart` (asks for password anyway). That command can be run from a shortcut or added into a `~/.local/share/applications/restart-wifi.desktop` file and run from slingshot.